# How to Efficiently Handle Large JSON Files in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, json, express, backend

I'm working on a **Node.js** project where I need to process large **JSON** files (several gigabytes in size). I'm looking for an efficient approach to handle such large files without exhausting memory resources.

I've tried using the fs module's **readFile** function to read the JSON file into memory, but this approach quickly becomes unmanageable for larger files. Are there any alternative strategies or libraries that can help me handle this situation effectively?

Here's a simplified version of the code I'm currently using:

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('largeFile.json', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err;

  // Process the JSON data
  const jsonData = JSON.parse(data);

  // Perform operations on jsonData

  // ...
});
```

Any suggestions or insights on how I can handle large JSON files efficiently in Node.js would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Streams to process a chunk at a time.